# React : how to change a specific div element style without changing it's children?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which holds a div root represent an image and within another div child that holds buttons.

the idea is that by clicking on a button to trigger a function that changes the state of filter but unfortunately, it changes also the button style.

how can I fix that?

```
 render() {
    return (
    <div className="main-div">
      <Lightbox
           images={[{src: this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)}]}
           isOpen={this.state.isExpand}
           onClose={this.closeLightBox}
           showImageCount={false}/>
      <div 
        className="image-root"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px',
          filter : this.state.filterType
        }}
        >
        <div>
          <a onClick={this.onClone}><FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="clone" title="clone"/></a>
          <a onClick={this.onFilter}><FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="filter" title="filter"/></a>
          <a onClick={this.onExpand}><FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="expand" title="expand"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide your code in codesandbox

Comment: like this?   https://codesandbox.io/s/nn8r6kxx70

Comment: please make sure it shows up properly and the problem you were asking could be reproduce through it

Comment: I'm not so familiar with codesandbox but this is the best I could do: https://codesandbox.io/s/13wx7n38lj